# converting a dataframe in given format

Tags: r

Given data frame values are

```
     Group          year       Value
     A              2010       17
     A              2011       18
     F              2010        8
     F              2011        9
```

i want to convert it into

```
          Year      A      F  
          2010     17      8
          2011     18      9
```

is there any simple solution to solve this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library('reshape2')

df <- read.table(text="     Group          year       Value
     A              2010       17
     A              2011       18
     F              2010        8
     F              2011        9", header = TRUE)

dfc <- dcast(df, year ~ Group )
```

Answer (score 3):

Although the syntax can be confusing, I still find reshape in base R useful to know. Using df provided by gauden

```
reshape_df <- reshape(df,dir="wide",idvar="year",timevar="Group")
colnames(reshape_df) <- c("year","A","F")
```

The converts to data from "long" format to "wide". Usually, the time variable becomes the column name, but in this case, we seek "A" and "F". Therefore, the syntax calls for timevar to be "Group".